# Android list screen custom background

Tags: android, listview, layout

I've a screen with the following layout

[image]

Also I've a list view

[image]

How can i bring a box like background (similar to first screen) for the list view

out may look like

[image]

Is it possible to do with ListView? any suggestions, i can post the code for the current layouts if necessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your list in a layout.. set the background and add padding ... for list listview again put up background.